# Using implicit differentiation, verify that $u=f(x-tu)$ satisfies $\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}+u(x,t)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

Using implicit differentiation, verify that $u=f(x-tu)$ satisfies $\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}+u(x,t)\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}$.

Could someone explain how implicit differentiation works with a pde? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiating $u=f(x-t\,u)$ first with respect to $t$ and then with respect to $x$ we get:
$$
u_t=f'(x-t\,u)(-u-t\,u_t),
$$
$$
u_x=f'(x-t\,u)(1-t\,u_x).
$$
Multiplying the second equation by $u$ and adding both equations we get
$$
u_t+u\,u_x=-t\,f'(x-t\,u)(u_t+u\,u_x)\implies (1+t\,f')(u_t+u\,u_x)=0.
$$
If $f'\ge0$ (i.e. $f$ is increasing) then $1+t\,f'>1$ for all $t\ge0$ and $u_t+u\,u_x=0$ follows.

If $f'<0$ at some point, there is a $T_{\text{max}}$ such that $1+t\,f'>0$ on $[0,T_{\text{max}})$,

Comment: So all I do is plug in what $u$ is? That's it?

Comment: But you do not know what $u$ is, do you? The equation $u=f(x-t\,u)$ defines $u$ implicitly. _All_ you have to do is solve for $u$.